# How do I prove: If $A$ is an infinite set and $x$ is some element such that $x$ is not in $A$, then$ A\sim A\cup \left\{x\right\}$.

Tags: set-theory

How do I prove: If $A$ is an infinite set and $x$ is some element such that $x$ is not in $A$, then$ A\sim A\cup \left\{x\right\}$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Since $A$ is infinite there is some $A_0\subseteq A$ such that $|A_0|=|\Bbb N|$. Show that $\Bbb N$ has the wanted property, conclude that $A_0$ has it, and then conclude that $A$ has it as well.

Comment: Since A is infinte, it has a denumerable subset. But how does that help us show A∼A∪{x}. Sorry i am a sophomore and its a graduate level course. So could You explain it to me in details plz.

Comment: @Ravi: First write a proof that $\Bbb N\sim\Bbb N\cup\{-1\}$. From there it should be almost obvious.

Comment: Thats where i failed actually. I made a function f:A to A such that f(a)= a but wont x be left out. so it there will be element in A∪{x} which is not being mapped to anything.

Comment: @Ravi: Again, come up with a function which maps $\Bbb N$ bijectively to $\Bbb N\cup\{-1\}$. Next, take a denumerable subset of $A$, and just "pull" the trick from $\Bbb N$ into $A_0$ and $A_0\cup\{x\}$. Lastly, any elements from $A\setminus A_0$ can go to itself.

Comment: can u provide me with the function plz. I cant figure it out and i have been working on this problem for like 4 days.

Comment: @Ravi: After all this effort you are going to give up? I am **sure** that you can come up with a function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N\cup\{-1\}$. Now replace $-1$ by $x$, next replace $n$ by some element $a_n\in A$, which follows from the infinitude of $A$. I really have no desire spoon feeding you.

Comment: I m not giving up not yet.I will solve this problem. And thanx for ur time and help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I solved it. Thanx for the help.

Comment: @Sohaif: Glad to hear that.