# Prove that if set $A$ is denumerable and $x\notin A$ then $A\cup \{x\}$ is denumerable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove that if set $A$ is denumerable and $x\notin A$ then $A\cup\{x\}$ is denumerable.

See if my solution works:

Since $A$ is denumerable, there exists $f: \mathbb{N} \to A$ such that $f$ is a bijection.

Define $g:\mathbb{N} \to A$, $$g(n)=\begin{cases}x,&\text{if $n=1$,}\\f(n),&\text{ if $n\neq 1$}\end{cases}$$

Claim: $g$ is also bijective.

Let $n_1, n_2\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g(n_1)=g(n_2)$.

If $g(n_1)=x$, then $n=1$. If $g(n_1)\neq g(n_2)$, then $g(n_1)=f(n_1)=g(n_2)=f(n_2)$. We have $f(n_1)=f(n_2)$. Since $f$ is a bijection, then $n_1=n_2$. Therefore $g$ is injective.

Let $b\in A\cup\{x\}$. There exists $n=1$ such that $g(n)=x=b$. If $n\neq 1$, then there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $g(m)=f(m)=b$. Since $f$ is bijective, there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(m)=b=g(m)$. So $g$ is surjective.

Therefore $g$ is bijective.

Therefore $A\cup \{x\}$ is denumerable.

Comment: Why people don't like this question...

Comment: I think people generally prefer to see some effort from question askers.

Comment: I'm not math major so I don't know remember how to type the notations out. I look up every notation while I type... So hard..

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then the [basic MatJaX tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) might be usefull to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354351/union-of-a-finite-set-and-a-countably-infinite-set-is-countably-infinite), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757641/how-to-prove-that-a-union-of-a-countably-infinite-set-and-a-finite-set-is-counta), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328998/how-do-i-prove-if-a-is-an-infinite-set-and-x-is-some-element-such-that-x?rq=1)... (actually, the last one is not really a good suggested duplicate, but I'll leave it as a reference).

Comment: @gebruiker this is very useful thank you!

Comment: Well, as it's been defined, I think $g$ is not surjective because you are missing $f(1)$. Though it's quite hard to read: using $x$ as both the argument and the element which is not in $A$ and the overall inconsistent use of variables weren't the wisest choices.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli g(1) is defined as g(1)=x. Sorry I don't know how to deal with the notation there.

Comment: Check my edit. Your question was kind of unreadable before.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD oh my god thank you. That's much better now.

Comment: @Young As I have already said: $g$ is indeed injective, but $f(1)\notin g(\Bbb N)$, therefore $g$ is not surjective because $A\nsubseteq g(\Bbb N)$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli then how do I refine my prove?

Comment: As in Fernando's answer: in the definition of $g$, you shift the $f(n)$-s one place to the right.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli ok I see now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is denumerable then it has the form

$A=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n,... \}$,

so $A\cup\{x\}$ can be written as

$A=\{x,a_1,a_2,...,a_n,... \}$,

then, if we write $b_1=x$, $b_2=a_1$, ... , $b_n=a_{n-1}$, ... ,

we have

$A=\{b_1,b_2,...,b_n,...\}$, which is a denumerable set

Comment: I understand the relation between x and A. But how do you prove? How do you write it down?

Comment: The subscript of the elements gives the injection on the set of natural numbers

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f:A\to\mathbb{N}$ is an injective function. Define $g:A\cup\{x\}\to\mathbb{N}$ as follows: $g(x)=0$ and $g(z)=f(z)+1$ for all $z\neq x$. The function $g$ as defined is injective. Indeed, consider $g(z)-g(y)$ for $z\neq y$. There are 3 cases:

- $y=x$: $g(z)-g(y)=g(z)-g(x)=g(z)\geq 1\neq 0$,
- $z=x$: $g(z)-g(y)=g(x)-g(y)=-g(y)\leq -1\neq 0$,
- $y,z\neq x$: $g(z)-g(y)=f(z)-f(y)$ which is nonzero due to the injectivity of $f$.

Comment: Could you explain why you define your g like that?

Comment: @Young It seems like an easy way to define some injective $g$. I'm sure there are many other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the perfect answer:

Since $A$ is denumerable, there exists $f: \mathbb{N} \to A$ such that $f$ is a bijection.

Define $g:\mathbb{N} \to A$, $$g(n)=\begin{cases}x,&\text{if $n=1$,}\\f(n-1),&\text{ if $n\neq 1$}\end{cases}$$

Claim: $g$ is also bijective.

Let $n_1, n_2\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g(n_1)=g(n_2)$.

If $g(n_1)=x$, then $n=1$. If $g(n_1)\neq g(n_2)$, then $g(n_1)=f(n_1-1)=g(n_2)=f(n_2-1)$. We have $f(n_1-1)=f(n_2-1)$. Since $f$ is a bijection, then $n_1=n_2$. Therefore $g$ is injective.

Let $b\in A\cup\{x\}$. There exists $n=1$ such that $g(n)=x=b$. If $n\neq 1$, then there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $g(m)=f(m-1)=b$. Since $f$ is bijective, there exists $m-1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(m-1)=b=g(m)$. Since $m-1\in \mathbb{N}$, $m \in \mathbb{N}$. So there exists m \in\mathbb{N} such that $g(m)=b$. Therefore $g$ is surjective.

Therefore $g$ is bijective.

Therefore $A\cup \{x\}$ is denumerable.